# Text not centered "properly" in small box

Tags: css

Here is how it works:
[how it works now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPAkP.png)
(the first paragraph is centered relative to small box)

And here is how I want it to be:
[how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMLYC.png)
(the second paragraph is no-wrap)

Comment: Show the code please!

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you are trying to actually do but the coding below will produce your second image:

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.box {
    width: 221px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: calc(100% - 16px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.para2 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <p class="para1">
    centered text
    </p>
    <p class="para2">
    second paragraph with no-wrap blah blah blah blah ...
    </p>
</div>
```

If this is not what you need then you MUST provide real substance and definitive information in your question.